# What happens when user update app from AppleStore

Tags: ios, app-store

If my app is in background state (home button) and user update app from AppleStore.

- The App will be killed ?
- If user click on the app icon, it will start from scratch by calling "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" ?

Comment: What else could happen when the entire app is deleted and replaced as part of the update process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, the executable is replaced so it has to be stopped, and yes, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` gets called when the user manually opens the app.